# How can I disable the legacy 8253/4 PIT?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, hardware

I am writing an OS kernel for the AMD64 architecture and would like to disable IRQ 0 (the legacy PIT) for complicated reasons I would rather not get into. (Besides, if I needed a timer, I would rather use the HPET or local APIC.) However, neither [osdever.net](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/pit.htm), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8253http://), or the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIT) talk about how to turn it off, only how to use it. Can anyone explain how to do this, ideally in a few `in`/`out` ASM instructions?

Comment: You could set the PIT to one-shot mode, and then once it fires, acknowledge the interrupt and don't reset the timer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing a kernel - the Silcos kernel, which you could find at GitHub. I have also faced this problem while developing  a timer subsystem framework for my kernel. In reality, there is no method to disable the PIT by configuring it, there may be a method which is motherboard specific, but we don't want to go there.

So what you need to do is that you have to generate periodic interrupts by the PIT with the maximum allowed period, to reduce its overhead when it isn't required. On each IRQ, you should build an IRQ subsystem like

```
//!
//! This class will manage a 'device' interrupt. As multiple devices may share
//! the same IRQ in the IOAPIC and even the CPU's LAPIC vectors, we must create
//! a queue for each IRQ entry. When an interrupt occurs, each IRQHandler is
//! checked using @code doesDeviceRequireService() and the first device to return
//! @code true is executed by @code action(). On this further checking is stopped
//!
//! @see IRQ
//! @see IRQ::trigger()
//!
class IRQHandler
{
public:
    void doesDeviceRequireService();//!< checks whether the device is triggering
                                    //< an interrupt.
    void action();//!< Executes the handler for the device-interrupt
protected:
    IRQHandler();//!< You could create classes like PIT, HPET which are IRQHandler           
                 //! which will have interrupt-handlers.
    ~IRQHandler();
};

//!
//! The IRQ class is a IOAPIC irq or a local IRQ. This will have a queue of IRQHandlers
//! and can be executed. You should have __irqCallback .asm function which will
//! invoke a 'C' function which calculates the IRQ class based on the given vector
//! and then calls execute() and then also does a EOI.
//!
//! @see IRQHandler
//!
class IRQ
{
public:
    void execute();//!< Tests all the IRQHandlers in the queue, and does the
                   //! action() if true is returned.

private:
    IRQ();
    ~IRQ();
};
```

which will handle multiple devices on one IRQ.